# When I type a value that should return a blank because it is null in my SSRS report, the report displays the previous searched value information

Tags: reporting-services

I have a form in which you have to type an invoice number and the date it was created.  If you type the wrong invoice number then the form should display blanks in the fields; however, it is displaying the information for the previous invoice number that was searched for.

Comment: I am using SSRS 2008

Comment: This isn't a whole lot of information to go on. What language is this form in? How is passing parameters to the report? Is the report hosted in SharePoint, Report Manager, or locally somewhere? Where is the previous information being displayed; in the form of the report? If the report is still showing previous information, what are your processing options set to where the report is hosted?